# Can't php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I was having a problem, did you know how to fix it? I'm using a web hosting server and trying to do that php artisan migrate

Exception trace:

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'u739920537_root'@'*********' (using password: YES)")
>   /Users/edvinasvalentinovicius/Desktop/testas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
> 2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=******;port=3306;dbname=u739920537_laravel", "u739920537_root", "*******", [])
>   /Users/edvinasvalentinovicius/Desktop/testas/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

Comment: The error message is pretty obvious. Access denied for user ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your [.env](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) file and set the correct database configuration([Link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example#L9-L14)):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name 
DB_USERNAME=           // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

Anytime you change a `.env` file you will need a clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`